# counting keys for dictionary, python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, count, increment

//edit - so I'm trying to find pairs of sum, but excluding duplicated pairs such as (n1,n2) and (n2,n1) [one of them to be ignored]

So this is part of my code, what im trying to achieve here is

1. From input -> number_list of int split() -> double for loops
2. count +=1 everytime it finds same [sum] key in the count_dict
3. count_dict[sum]=count records of how many of same sum different int pairs gets recorded.

but I can't seem to figure out how to increment count variable correctly
please advice me, thank you!

```
count=1
for n1 in number_list:
    for n2 in number_list:

        sum=n1+n2

        if (n2,n1) not in pair_dict and n1!=n2:
            pair_dict[(n1,n2)]=sum
            sum_dict[sum]=(n1,n2)
            if sum_dict[sum]==(n2,n1):
                count_dict[sum]=count
            else:
                count+=1
                count_dict[sum]=count
        else:
            pass
```

Test case

2 1 3 4

> > 5

10 20 40 45 5 15 25

> > 25

24 23 8 29 31 5

> > None

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you can initialize all `count_dict` values to `0` and then do `count_dict[sum]+=1` each time.

Comment: If you share a sample of your data you will get an answer much faster.

Comment: Can you provide an input case please?

Comment: Sample input
2 1 3 4     => 5
10 20 40 45 5 15 25    => 25
24 23 8 29 31 5    => None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top part of your question, it looks like you are trying to find the sum of each pair of elements in a list and count the number of times that each sum occurs.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum_counter = Counter(map(sum, combinations(number_list, 2)))

print(sum_counter)
# {3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

This can be readily generalized to count the sums of triplets, quadruplets, and so on, by changing the `2` in the arugment for `combinations`.

Comment: you can do that in one line with collections.Counter: `sum_counter = Counter(map(sum,combinations(number_list, 2)))`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
count=1
for n1 in number_list:
    for n2 in number_list:

        sum=n1+n2

        if (n2,n1) not in pair_dict and n1!=n2:
            pair_dict[(n1,n2)]=sum
            sum_dict[sum]=(n1,n2)
            if sum_dict[sum]==(n2,n1):
                count_dict[sum]=count
            else:
                count+=1
                count_dict[sum]+=count
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `if sum_dict[sum]==(n2,n1):` - this condition is never true, because in previous line `sum_dict[sum]` is set to `(n1, n2)`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek *and* because `n1 != n2` from the previous `if`

Comment: Please provide me an input?